# Парсинг XML и многопоточность C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, парсер, асинхронность

Пишу программку для автоматического редактирования XML документа, саму логику работы программы сделал, а вот нормально распарсить ее не могу.
Проблема в том, что представление XML такое:

```
<тег>Текст<тег><тег>Текст<тег></тег></тег></тег></тег>
```

XML огромных размеров и это всё в одну строку.
Нужно ее разбить в массив вытянуть и теги, и текст, это для того, чтобы потом обратно сформировать файл и склеить переменные, которые разбиты тегами...

```
richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FileXML);
Status.Text = "Файл открыт";
StatusProc.Text = "100%";

string text1 = "";
string Ot = "";
private void ObrFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    text1 = richTextBox1.Text;
    Status.Text = "Обработка файла.";
    obr();   
}
public async void obr()
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    StatusProc.Text = "0%";
    progressBar1.Maximum = text1.Length - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < text1.Length; j++)
    {
        Ot += await ooo(text1[j]);
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
        double a = j / (Convert.ToInt32(text1.Length - 1) / 100);
        StatusProc.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(a, 2)) + "%";
    }
    string[] Otext = Ot.Split('^');

    Status.Text = "Вывод обработанного файла.";

    obrV(Otext);
}
public Task<string> ooo(char text1)
{
    string t = "";
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (text1 == '<')
        {
            t += "^";
        }
        if (text1 == '>')
        {
            t += text1 + "^";
        }
        else
        t += text1;
        return t;
    });
}

public async void obrV(string[] Otext)
{
    StatusProc.Text = "0%";
    progressBar1.Maximum = Otext.Length - 1;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Otext.Length; i++)
    {
        richTextBox2.Text += await aaa(Otext[i]);
        //progressBar1.Value += 1;
        double a = i / (Convert.ToInt32(text1.Length - 1) / 100);
        StatusProc.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(a, 2)) + "%";
    }

}
static Task<string> aaa(string Otext)
{
    string oo = "";
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
            oo += Otext + "\n";
        return oo;
    });
}
```

знаю, код кривой и тупой, делался на скорую руку, да и шарпы подзабыл...
ну а так как файлы большие (более метра) обработка занимает немало времени. Это ещё и нужно сделать в многопоточном режиме, чтобы не лагала форма.

Comment: Для начала, у вас куча лишнего кода. Во-вторых, вы почему-то выгружаете в другой поток тривиальную операцию. В-третьих, не вижу, где в вашем коде разбор XML, есть только посимвольная обработка.

Comment: Покажите, что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: бедные воробушки от вашей пушки... А по факту, думаю https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx стандартными средствами распарсить удастся

Comment: @xSx тогда уж лучше `XDocument` если стандартные средства. Он по легче и по шустрее будет, да и `LiNQ` понимает.

Comment: Вся суть посимвольной обработки в том что вставляются символы перед и после тега и по ним идёт сплит... 
что разбивает всю строку на массив
что позволяет нормально работать с ним...

Comment: И ещё какие теги встретятся без понятия они изменяются в зависимости от содержимого файла...

Comment: Итог данной функции строка разбитая в массив со всеми тегами и текстом

Comment: Спрашиваю ещё раз: покажите (отредактируйте вопрос), что должно получиться в итоге! Если на вход подать тот xml, что у вас в начале, то что и в каком виде должно попасть в массив?

Comment: проще показать 
Это исходная XML
http://joxi.ru/bmo0N8dtwo4N2y
а это итог после разбития 
http://joxi.ru/D2P37XEtv15km3
после чего идёт работа с ним 
Теги разбивают переменные, пример:
http://joxi.ru/Drlby1lcengZ2P
в верху разбитая переменная, а ниже склеена,
второй алгоритм ищет их и склеивает, он работает нормально, а вот с парсовкой проблемы из-за того что она долгая

Comment: я так понимаю это у вас вордовский шаблон для загрузки данных? Тогда тем более стоит смотреть в сторону стандартных средств, а если не поленитесь и вытянете XSD из этой XML, она там встроенная если что, и напишете простенькую XSLT чтобы удалить лишние теги форматирования... руками парсить такой XML - героизм конечно, но на грани с идиотизмом, уж извините за прямоту. Если скинете полный образец файла могу попробовать накидать пример, просто с обрывком файла сложной структуры, сами понимаете, много не сделаешь.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb669147.aspx а вот вам и наводка на правильное решение от самого микрософта

Comment: Спасибо большое, изучу завтра дам окончательный ответ получилось или нет

Answer (score -1):

Настоятельно советую парсить XML с помощью htmlAgilityPack.

Парсил не раз и никаких проблем не было. Хотя, я все равно писал некую надстройку над ним для своего удобства.

Comment: Вы, наверное, перепутали `XML` с `HTML`? ;)

Comment: нет, не перепутал.

Comment: В таком случае вы выбрали неправильный инструмент. Во всяком случае я не знаю никаких преимуществ от использования `HtmlAgilityPack` при работе с `xml`. Вы не могли бы описать подробнее какие плюсы есть у вашего подхода?

Comment: Я пробовал работать с XDocument и мне не понравилось. Недостаточная интуитивность в работе с ним, а так же большая громоздкость кода с ним была. + в моем случае еще и возможность парсить хтмл по Xpath, что мне так же нужно было. Большая громоздкость кода за собой влечет хреновое ориентирование в коде и прибавляет возможность пропустить ошибку. Код всегда должен быть простым и легко читабельным. С htmlAgilityPack этого добится в разы легче. Сравни простой перебор дочерних нод там и там. По функционалу не знаю никаких преимуществ, но не уверен в их отсутствии в какой-либо из сторон.

Comment: Если вам не нравится Linq2XML вы можете использовать привычный `XmlDocument`, где есть возможность работать с `XPath`